# Needing help creating an fluorescent glass shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How can I make this glowing glass material like this?...

[image: fluorescent glass]

Comment: use a glass shader with an emission shader plugged into volume

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add *Emission* shader to the *Volume* input of *Material Output* node:

[image]

Further you can also add in Volumetric Absorption and Scatter nodes to simulate a real medium inside, not just light originating from the volume.

Comment: Phoof this is slick!

Comment: Well, thanks! I want to use it my project.

Comment: How would you go about the use of Volumetric Absorption and scatter nodes? I would really love to see a material build on this, to simulate a medium!

Comment: @sorenfroststaal You just add Absorption and Scatter nodes together with Add Shader and you add that to the Emission also with Add Shader. You will have to bump the energy on the emission a bit, because the light will scatter in the volume and will get absorbed by the volume too. It's more realistic, but the render time is much longer and the visual is not that different.